# Where is the jquery.cycle.all.js file?

Tags: javascript, 8

So i have install views_slideshow_cycle module, and it always shows "cycle" is not a function. after some googling, I found out I have to install jquery_cycle.

In views_slideshow_cycle.libraries.yml file, I found this section:

```
jquery_cycle:
  remote: http://malsup.github.io/jquery.cycle.all.js
  version: 3.0.3
  license:
    name: MIT
    url: http://jquery.malsup.com/license.html
    gpl-compatible: true
  js:
    /libraries/jquery.cycle/jquery.cycle.all.js: {}
  dependencies:
    - core/jquery
```

Where is that *libraries* directory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, I have found out, you have to create a libraries folder under web root.

Answer (score 0):

Also you can fine this `library` folder in `/sites/all/libraries`.
If it is not present then you have to create this folder because it is not created by default.